# Bash string regex replace with ".*"

Tags: regex, bash

for a string

```
s='abc_somedef'
```

use regex replace (it works)

```
echo ${s//_some/}
```

use regex replace with **`.*`** (it NOT works)

```
echo ${s//^.*_some/}
```

I want the result to be `def`

how I write it with bash internally (not sed/awk) ? maybe some escape char ?

Comment: Maybe use non-greedy version of `*`: `/^.*?_some/`?

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
echo ${s//*_some/}
```

Your version didn't match since it was trying to match a dot literally.

**UPDATE:**

Chepner has correctly explained below that `*` here is not part of a regex at all. It is simply being used as a globbing character.

Comment: You could have made this 30 character long by _explaining_ why OPs version doesn't work.

Comment: "Unlike the regexes in most languages...": not true. Parameter expansion does not *use* regular expressions; it uses pattern matching. Where `bash` does use regular expressions (after the `=~` operator), `.` has the standard meaning of "any single character".